# Copy Video from Library to DocumentsDocument directory

Tags: ios, video, nsdata, alasset, file-copying

I am building a task in ios app where, I want to copy the video from library to local app Documents Directory.
I have successfully fetch the ALAssest List from Library in an array.
Now when I try to copy any video from ALAssest url to our file I am always getting the following error

> " Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 262.)" UserInfo=0x157d4a70
>   {NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.m4v?id=B01C37C9-8C8C-4963-BAC8-EE0356C079DD&ext=m4v"

I have made a folder in document directory to store video

```
NSString *path;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppVideo"];
NSError *error=nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])    //Does directory already exist?
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePath
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"pathToPatientPhotoFolder filePath=%@",filePath);
}
```

Below is the code for copying data

```
NSError *error=nil;

NSString *path;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppVideo"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myvideo.mp4"];
NSURL * url=nil;
 url=[[[self.dataContainer objectAtIndex:selected] defaultRepresentation] url];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:url toURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] error:&error];

if(error)
    NSLog(@"Writing Error=%@",error.description);
else
    NSLog(@"writing has done without error");
`
```

I have also tried to writing NSData of ALAssest url to file but when I play this with MPMoviePlayerViewController it show only black screen

```
 ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[self.dataContainer objectAtIndex:selected] defaultRepresentation];

Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
NSData *FileData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:NO];


[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                        contents:FileData
                                      attributes:nil];
```

but find no any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved my problem for writing ALAsest Data to Directroy path i used

```
 ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myAssest defaultRepresentation];

Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((NSUInteger)rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)rep.size error:nil];
dty = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:NO];
[dty writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

and to play this file

```
NSString *path;
NSArray *paths =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppVideo"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",MyString]];

self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];
[self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.videoController];
[self.videoController play];
```

Answer (score 2):

Real problem a little deeper. You should to call

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:<# string path #>]
```

instead of

```
[NSURL URLWithString:path]
```

If you're working with a file system you have to use specific URLs.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSError_Codes) you can see that it is an error corresponding to `NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError = 262`. Looks like you can't move or copy file from library, however, if you get `NSData` from library asset, using `writeTofile` to a file in document directory will work.

Comment: Gabber i have checked that the writing of NSData is done as per you told.But The new video file is not play with MPMoviePlayerController ,only black screen showing with moving activity indicator. The code for play is following :

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController  *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];                       
`

Comment: [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
                        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
                        [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES];
                        [moviePlayerController play];

Comment: when i tried to save this new written video file in Device Photo Album its saved successfully.I have also play this video in album.  `ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:path]])
            {
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:path]
                                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
                {
 }
                }
                 ];
            }`

Comment: No, I mean save to the document directory, not the photo album.

Comment: Also try to use `fileURLWithString`, If it still doesn't work, can share your whole code?

Comment: Yes gabber you are right . fileURLWithString will use for make url of movie player.Now my problem has solved.Thnx!

Comment: I see, glad you fixed it.